# Parse Json data into Custom Object C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a Json structure see code below.

```
"attributes": {
    "13448": {
        "id": 13448,
        "name": {
            "sv": "H\u00f6jd",
            "en": "Length",
            "nb": "Lengde",
            "de": "",
            "da": "L\u00e6ngde",
            "fi": "Pituus"
        },
        "value": {
            "sv": "Sanderson",
            "en": "Sanderson",
            "nb": "Sanderson",
            "de": null,
            "da": "Sanderson",
            "fi": "Sanderson"
        }
    },
    "13910": {
        "id": 13910,
        "name": {
            "sv": "H\u00f6jd",
            "en": "Length",
            "nb": "Lengde",
            "de": "",
            "da": "L\u00e6ngde",
            "fi": "Pituus"
        },
        "value": {
            "sv": "50s Collection",
            "en": "50s Collection",
            "nb": "50s Collection",
            "de": null,
            "da": "50s Collection",
            "fi": "50s Collection"
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to serialize into a custom object where i only would like to have value from **name** as a key in a dictionary.
And store **value** as value in that dictionary.

```
Key      | Value   |
--------------------
H\u00f6jd|Sanderson|
Length   |Sanderson|
```

So my code i at the moment:

```
foreach(var item in obj["attributes"])
{
     var attribute = item.First["name"].ToObject<ArticleAttributes>();
     var attribute = item.First["value"].ToObject<ArticleAttributes>();
}
```

And my ArticleAttributes class looks like :

```
public class ArticleAttributes
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without writing a *json converter* for your specific case, the closest thing would be:

```
var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string,string> Name { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Value { get; set; }
}


public class RootObject
{
    public Dictionary<string, Item> Attributes { get; set; }
}
```

You can further process your result.

```
var finalres = res.Attributes
                    .ToDictionary(
                        x => x.Value.Id, 
                        x => x.Value.Value.Keys
                              .ToLookup(y => x.Value.Name[y], y => x.Value.Value[y]));
```

Now you can use it as:

```
var val = finalres[13448]["Lengde"].FirstOrDefault();
```